# assert the size of the list in elixir

Tags: elixir

I would like to assert list's size. Currently I do it as follows:

```
assert devices = Repo.all from d in device, where d.uuid == ^attrs.uuid
assert devices.first == devices.last
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Kernel.length/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#length/1) will return the size of a list:

```
length([1,2,3]) #3
```

You can do this from an Ecto query using:

```
query = from d in Device, where: d.uuid == ^uuid, select: fragment("count(?)", d.id)
assert  Repo.all(query)== 3
```

In Ecto 2 you can use [Repo.aggregate/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Repo.html#c:aggregate/4)

```
query = from d in Device, where: d.uuid == ^uuid)
assert Repo.aggregate(query, :count, :id) == 3
```

Comment: is there any difference/benefit from using Enum,count or Kernel.length?

Comment: They use the exact same function https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.2.5/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L453 https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.2.5/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L452 - you skip a pattern match when using length. I will update the answer to use length instead.

Comment: I would also suggest doing `assert [devide] = Repo.all(...)` if you need the record and want to make sure there's just one.

Comment: @michalmuskala Thanks I forgot about that

Comment: `count` vs. `length` is discussed [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@kana_sama/length-vs-amount-37a1c431141a). The blog author's point in TL;DR is: »length is more preferred way to get length of the list, but it is better to use count for enumerations: streams, ranges, custom iterators» (see the post for his reasoning on why).